# Get telegram channel "Recent Actions" via telegram's Client API Or Bot API?

Tags: telegram

Is it possible to get my telegram channel's "**Recent Actions**"?

Main reason for doing that, is to get members who joined the channel or left it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't supported by bot API, and no existing library can do this.

You can use [channels.getAdminLog#33ddf480](https://schema.horner.tj/#!/method/channels.getAdminLog) in MTProto.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the right way to go for getting "recent actions", yet I don't know how to use "channels.getAdminLog". If you had any comments on how to use it in C#, that would be awesome :)